# Python selenium: Element not interactable

Tags: python, selenium, warnings

I tried to code a web automation with python but always get the error warning:

selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

Here is the code:

```
def commentAndLike():
random.seed()
likeOrNext = random.randint(0, 3)

if likeOrNext == 0:
    if check_exists_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/article/div[2]/section[1]/span[1]/button/span"):
        likeButton = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/article/div[2]/section[1]/span[1]/button/span")
        likeButton.click()

        time.sleep(randomNumber(6, 10))

        if check_exists_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/article/div[2]/section[1]/span[2]/button/span"):
            random.seed()
            randomComment = random.randint(0, 3)

            textArea = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/article/div[2]/section[3]/div[1]/form/textarea")

            if randomComment == 0:
                textArea.send_keys(comments[0])
            elif randomComment == 1:
                textArea.send_keys(comments[1])
            elif randomComment == 2:
                textArea.send_keys(comments[2])
            elif randomComment == 3:
                textArea.send_keys(comments[3])

            time.sleep(randomNumber(15,30))

            postButton = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/article/div[2]/section[3]/div/form/button")
            postButton.click()

            time.sleep(randomNumber(20,25))

            nextButton2 = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/a[2]")
            nextButton2.click()

            time.sleep(randomNumber(15,20))

        else:
            nextButton4 = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/a[2]")
            nextButton4.click()

            time.sleep(randomNumber(20, 25))

    else:
        nextButton1 = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/a[2]")
        nextButton1.click()

        time.sleep(randomNumber(20, 25))

else:
    nextButton = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/a[2]")
    nextButton.click()

    time.sleep(randomNumber(20,25))
```

The error gets thrown when attempting to `send_keys` to the `textArea` element.

I know I will still have to improve the code and shorten the nextButton out, but I want to solve the problems at first. Thank you for all your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Modified based on problem description where sending keys to `textArea` is throwing an error.

You can try to use Javascript to set the value of the textarea:

```
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].value = 'myValue';", textArea)
```

If this does not work, you could try clicking the textArea to activate it first:

```
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", textArea)

browser.execute_script("arguments[0].value = 'myValue';", textArea);
```

In your case, you would replace `'myValue'` with `' + comments[0] + '`

Comment: this isn't the issue, the problem is that the Webdriver can't send_keys to textArea

Comment: It would help if you included which line of code is throwing the error in your problem description. Posting a program as long as yours, and saying there's an error, doesn't tell us much if we don't know what line it is on. You can set the text area value using `browser.execute_script("arguments[0].value = 'myValue';", textArea)`

Comment: and what is myValue?

Comment: Whatever value you wish to set the text area to. In your case, it will be `comments[0]` -- depending on your loop index. I've updated my answer with a more specific solution.

Comment: I do this for instagram, but when I just paste the text into the comment field I cannot post it, any idea how to solve it

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'I cannot post it'? Is there an error or exception thrown? Does the text appear in the comment field at all? Is the 'Post' button disabled?

Comment: The post button is hidden, only if I enter text into textArea you can press the post button

Answer (score 0):

This kind of exception is thrown to indicate that although an element is present on the DOM, it is not in a state that can be interacted with. You can try to implement some kind of wait mechanism, preferably an explicit one like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

textArea = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/article/div[2]/section[3]/div[1]/form/textarea"))
```